# How to toggle classes with with Gatsby link

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, bulma

I am using Gatsby and Bulma css.

I can't toggle the classes on the 'navMenu' and get the to navigation (visual) change in accordance to device screen size. The changes will effect the 'a' element, but not the corresponding 'navMenu' element. The 'a' element will change the 'burger' icon to a 'cross' icon which is expected.

Here is my code

```
    <nav className="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div className="navbar-brand">
        <a href="#"
          role="button"
          className={`navbar-burger burger ${isActive? ' is-active' : ' '}`} onClick={()=> {isActive = !isActive}}
          aria-label="menu"
          data-target="navMenu"
          aria-expanded="true"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
      </div>


      <div  id="navMenu" className="navbar-menu">
        <div className="navbar-start">
          <a className="navbar-item">Home</a>

          <a className="navbar-item">Documentation</a>

          <div className="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
            <a className="navbar-link">More</a>

            <div className="navbar-dropdown">
              <a className="navbar-item">About</a>
              <a className="navbar-item">Jobs</a>
              <a className="navbar-item">Contact</a>
              <hr lass="navbar-divider"></hr>
              <a className="navbar-item">Report an issue</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="navbar-end">
          <div className="navbar-item">
            <div className="buttons">
              <a className="button is-primary">
                <strong>Sign up</strong>
              </a>
              <a className="button is-light">Log in</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

I would like the 'navMenu' to show up whenever the onClick event is raised.

Thanks

Comment: For dynamic classes i'm use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should works :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./style.scss";


class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { active: false };
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });
   };
render() {

 return (
  <nav className="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
    <div className="navbar-brand">
      <a className="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
        <img
          src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png"
          style={{ width: "112", height: "28" }}
          alt=""
        />
      </a>

      <span
        role="button"
        className={
          "navbar-burger burger " + (this.state.active ? "is-active" : "")
        }
        aria-label="menu"
        aria-expanded="false"
        data-target="navbarBasicExample"
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div
      id="navbarBasicExample"
      className={"navbar-menu " + (this.state.active ? "is-active" : "")}
    >
      <div className="navbar-start">
        <a className="navbar-item">Home</a>

        <a className="navbar-item">Documentation</a>

        <div className="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
          <a className="navbar-link">More</a>

          <div className="navbar-dropdown">
            <a className="navbar-item">About</a>
            <a className="navbar-item">Jobs</a>
            <a className="navbar-item">Contact</a>
            <hr className="navbar-divider" />
            <a className="navbar-item">Report an issue</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="navbar-end">
        <div className="navbar-item">
          <div className="buttons">
            <a className="button is-primary">
              <strong>Sign up</strong>
            </a>
            <a className="button is-light">Log in</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Example on codesandbox.io : https://codesandbox.io/s/bulma-reactjs-toggle-menu-hxux4

Answer (score 1):

Use classnames to easy manage class.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import cs from 'classnames';

class Page extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
                isActive: false
        }
    }

    render() {

        const { isActive } = this.state

        return (
                <nav className="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
                    <div className="navbar-brand">
                        <a href="#"
                            role="button"
                            className={cs('navbar-burger burger',{ 'is-active': isActive })} onClick={()=> { this.setState({ isActive: !isActive }) }}
                            aria-label="menu"
                            data-target="navMenu"
                            aria-expanded="true"
                        >
                            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>


                    <div  id="navMenu" className="navbar-menu">
                        <div className="navbar-start">
                            <a className="navbar-item">Home</a>

                            <a className="navbar-item">Documentation</a>

                            <div className="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
                                <a className="navbar-link">More</a>

                                <div className="navbar-dropdown">
                                    <a className="navbar-item">About</a>
                                    <a className="navbar-item">Jobs</a>
                                    <a className="navbar-item">Contact</a>
                                    <hr lass="navbar-divider"></hr>
                                    <a className="navbar-item">Report an issue</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="navbar-end">
                            <div className="navbar-item">
                                <div className="buttons">
                                    <a className="button is-primary">
                                        <strong>Sign up</strong>
                                    </a>
                                    <a className="button is-light">Log in</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            )

    }

}
```

Comment: Du you recommend that I wrap my code inside a class structure? Will this add to the support of state?

Comment: No. I'm sow you how use classnames and change state of isActive.